# ARR with Multiple application with multiple Ports on both server

Tags: iis-8

I have a test environment where I want to install my two applications on IIS. 
lets say i install app1 on port 789 and another app app2 on port 790.
i want to install these app in two servers for load balancing using ARR.
Can anyone tell me how this can be done.

Comment: There is not enough to go off of here. You have 2 apps you and you want to load balance between them? Or you have 2 apps and you want each of them to be load balanced? (Totaling 4 copies of 2 apps?)

Comment: I have 2 apps and want each of them to be load balanced but they are running on same server on different ports.